# Show/hide by post id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use some script to hide full content , but i have problem this only hide my first div in while.

script:

```
$('#blah').css({height:'20px', overflow:'hidden'});
$('#blah').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('open')) {
        $this.animate({height:'20px'});
        $this.data('open', 0);

    }
    else {
        $this.animate({height:'100%'});
        $this.data('open', 1);
    }
});
```

And while php code , just wanna to show all rows from database and all result from db must to be hidden not just the first one..

PHP code:

```
 $fq = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT");
             while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($fq)){

           echo "
                <div id='blah'>$link</div>
           ";   

}
```

I just wanna to all results from db be hidden and can be ellapsed by postid , anyhelp?

Best regards

Comment: Change it to: `$(document).on('click', 'div#blah', function() {...`.

Comment: `..., even then }`; *fail*.

Comment: What's the `LIMIT` doing?

Comment: Also the bit `<div id='blah'>` is going to present a problem because you can't have more than one element with the same id. You must use a css class if you want to assign it to multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting elements via jQuery using ID only selects the **first** occurence.
If you want to select many elements, dont use **ID**, use **Class**

```
while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($fq)){

           echo "
                <div class='blah'>$link</div>
           ";   

}
```

On you script :

```
$('.blah').css({height:'20px', overflow:'hidden'});
    $('.blah').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('open')) {
            $this.animate({height:'20px'});
            $this.data('open', 0);

        }
        else {
            $this.animate({height:'100%'});
            $this.data('open', 1);
        }
    });
```